# the difference between the present perfect simple and continuous - She's been playing tennis since she was eight

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> She's been playing tennis since she was eight.

Does the meaning of the sentence above change if I use the present perfect simple as below?

> She's played tennis since she was eight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is no significant change in meaning.

> She's played tennis since she was eight.

could be used if she played all that time, but has now stopped, while the first form could not. But standing alone, it would never be interpreted that way.

> She's played tennis since she was eight, but now she devotes all her time to social media.

adds the context to mark the action of playing tennis as completed and wholly in the past.